# Angular Reactive Forms - Call API on change event

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms, switchmap

I have a component that contains a table with exercise data and one input to search by name. The following code works perfectly.

```
searchTerm: FormControl;
searchTerms$: Observable<string>;
exercises$: Observable<Exercise[]>;

constructor(
    private _exerciseService: ExerciseService,
  ) {
    this.searchTerm = new FormControl();
    this.searchTerms$ = this.searchTerm.valueChanges;
    this.exercises$ = this.searchTerms$.pipe(
      startWith('' as string),
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(searchTerm => this._exerciseService.getExercisesByOrganization({ name: searchTerm, limit: 30, filter: 'full', offset: 0 }).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return EMPTY;
        }))
      ),
      map((data) => data)
    );
  }
```

But now, I have to implement more filters for the search (exercise type, with/without equipment, categories, etc) so I want to create a reactive form and include those fields. Something like this:

```
exerciseForm: FormGroup;
exerciseForm$: Observable<FormGroup>;
exercises$: Observable<Exercise[]>;

constructor(
    private _exerciseService: ExerciseService,
  ) {
    this.exerciseForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl('', []),
      requireEquipment: new FormControl(false, []),
      exerciseType: new FormControl('', []),
    });
    this.exerciseForm$ = this.exerciseForm.valueChanges;
    this.exercises$ = this.searchTerms$.pipe(
      startWith('' as string),
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(formValue => this._exerciseService.getExercisesByOrganization(formValue).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return EMPTY;
        }))
      ),
      map((data) => data)
    );
  }
```

In this way, I can send the full form to the backend based on the filters selected. My question is how can I do that since "formValue" in the `switchMap` is not the value of the exercise form. I would like to send the **JSON** (maybe using the `"getRawValue()"` function of the Reactive Form) to the backend and handle the logic in there based on user search and filters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `withLatestFrom()` to pass your form group object downstream

```
  this.exercises$ = this.searchTerms$.pipe(
      startWith('' as string),
      debounceTime(1000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      withLatestFrom(this.exerciseForm)
      switchMap(([searchTerm,formGroup] =>...
```